# How to write a polynomial function that has the roots $-2$ and $\sqrt7$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

I need to write a polynomial function with integer coefficients that has the roots $-2$ and $\sqrt7$. I'm able to do this correctly when I'm given roots like $-3+i$ & $-3-i$, in which I set the roots equal to zero and then multiply them by one another. However, when I try this with $-2$ and $\sqrt7$ and multiply $x+2$ by $x-\sqrt7$, I get $x^2+2x-\sqrt7 x-2\sqrt7$. I don't know where to go from here, and I don't think that this is the correct next step. What do I do next?

Comment: Your polynomial has roots $-2$ and $\sqrt7$, but if you want one with rational coefficients, multiply by $x+\sqrt7$ too

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  "make the roots equal to zero" is not worded well

Comment: There' s no reason to assume a $2$ degree polynomial with roots $-2, \sqrt 7$ will have integer coefficient unless $-2\cdot \sqrt 7$ and $-2+\sqrt 7$ are both integers.  Which they are not.  $(x-\sqrt 7)(x+2)$ is indeed the *second* degree polynomial with those roots but it, not surprisingly, doesn't have integer coefficients.  So to have integer coefficients it must be a higher degree and have a third unspecified root.  Preview:  the irrational conjugate to $\sqrt 7$ is $-\sqrt 7$ so you will learn you can make that the third root.

Comment: I don't think you set the roots equal to zero.  Perhaps you take $x-r$, where $r$ is a root

Comment: In other words, you set the linear factor $x-r$ equal to zero when $x$ is a root

Answer (score 2):

Try multiplying by $x+\sqrt7,$ the [conjugate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_(square_roots)) of $x-\sqrt7$, as well.

$(x+\sqrt7)(x-\sqrt7)=x^2-7$ has integer coefficients, and its product with $x+2$ will too.

Answer (score 0):

$x = \sqrt 7 \implies$

$x^2 = 7\implies$

$x^2 - 7 =0$.  So $x^2 -7$ has $\sqrt 7$ as a root.

And $x=-20\implies x+2 = 0$ so $x+2$ has $-2$ as a root.

If $x^2-7=0$ and $x+2=0$ then $(x^2-7)(x+2)=0$ and $(x^2-7)(x+2)=x^3+2x^2-7x-14$ has $\sqrt 7$ and $-2$ as roots.

(It also has $-\sqrt 7$ as a root.)

=====

By the way.  There is *no* 2nd degree polynomial with two roots $-2$ and $\sqrt 7$.

A second degree polynomial has at most two roots and if the two roots are $r_1$ and $r_2$ the polynomial is $(x-r_1)(x-r_2)= x^2 -(r_1+r_2)x + r_1r_2$ and if $r_1$ or $r_2$ are irrational we have no reason to assume $r_1+r_2$ or $r_1r_2$ are integers.

Is if $r_1,r_2 = -2,\sqrt 7$ they won't be.  But to counter $\sqrt 7$ as a root we can add a third root of $-\sqrt 7$ to get a *third* degree polynomial:

$(x-\sqrt 7)(x+\sqrt 7)(x+2) = x^3+2x^2-7x-14$.